# Best approach for splitting a view for small screens and MVVM?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

In my Windows 10 app, there is a complex view with clearly 3 blocks. Each block has multiple controls. In the desktop version, I want to show all 3 blocks in the same page. For the phone version, I want that each block is a different page.

How is the best approach for this scenario?

One ViewModel and multiple pages?  UserControls and each user control with one ModelView? ....

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what I would consider to be the "best" approach, but personally I would set up a viewmodel for each block, so that you can easily assign them to both the sections on the desktop and to individual pages on mobile.

on desktop I would add an additional viewmodel to the page that contains the blocks, with references to the three viewmodels within. on the page, you'd bind the mainviewmodel to the page, then the child viewmodels to each section so they have their own context.

you can use the mainviewmodel on the desktop to handle loading and saving state for the child views as needed, and on mobile just handle these directly.

i hope this is helpful!